# Recommendations to Find a Solution for Importing Files to MySQL

Tags: excel, csv, power-automate

How are you?

My project is basically an automated report using Python and MySQL as the development tools.

I export the report from the company's system in Excel (xlsx) format and use a power automate flow to transfer these files to a folder on my computer, and then import them into MySQL.

As you may have noticed, this approach doesn't work as intended in MySQL, since it requires the file to be in CSV format. Unfortunately, this presents a challenge, as my company only provides the reports in xls or xlsx formats. I have come across some sites that use a .bat file and a converter to automatically change the format, but I'm unable to use any type of converter due to company policies.

As a beginner in programming, this situation is quite complex for me. If you have any ideas on how to find a solution to this, please feel free to comment; every thought is valid. Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: You can use SSIS with excel and mysql drivers to do the import for you. Or just use excel's save as functionality to export its contents as csv